# Suggestions on how to update equation?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, tkinter, floating-point

After discovering [Float Toy](http://evanw.github.io/float-toy/), my goal was to create my own version using Python and Tkinter. The results of the endeavor is shown below. Most of the functionality is complete, but the `Equation` widget does not automatically update itself yet. Does anyone have any simple suggestions for updating its labels?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# http://evanw.github.io/float-toy/
import struct
import tkinter.ttk
from tkinter.constants import *


class FloatToy(tkinter.ttk.Frame):

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        tkinter.NoDefaultRoot()
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        cls.create_styles(root)
        root.title('Float Toy')
        root.resizable(False, False)
        toy = cls(root)
        toy.grid()
        root.mainloop()

    @staticmethod
    def create_styles(root):
        style = tkinter.ttk.Style(root)
        style.configure('S.TButton', background='#88F')
        style.configure('E.TButton', background='#8F8')
        style.configure('F.TButton', background='#F88')
        style.configure('S.TLabel', background='#CCF')
        style.configure('E.TLabel', background='#CFC')
        style.configure('F.TLabel', background='#FCC')

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.instructions = tkinter.ttk.Label(self)
        self.example_32 = Example(32, self)
        self.example_64 = Example(64, self)
        self.configure_all()
        self.grid_all()

    def configure_all(self):
        self.instructions['text'] = 'Click on a cell below to toggle bit ' \
                                    'values. Use this to build intuition ' \
                                    'for the IEEE float-point format.'

    def grid_all(self):
        self.instructions.grid(padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
        self.example_32.grid(padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
        self.example_64.grid(padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)


class Example(tkinter.ttk.Labelframe):

    def __init__(self, width, master=None, **kw):
        kw['text'] = f'{width}-bit (float)'
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.float = tkinter.DoubleVar(self)
        self.bits = Bits(width, self.float, self)
        self.equals = tkinter.ttk.Label(self)
        self.equation = Equation(width, self.float, self)
        self.configure_all()
        self.grid_all()

    def configure_all(self):
        self.float.trace_add('write', self.update_equals)
        self.float.set(1.0)

    def update_equals(self, *_):
        self.equals.configure(text=f' = {self.float.get()}')

    def grid_all(self):
        self.bits.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.equals.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.equation.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)


class Bits(tkinter.ttk.Frame):

    STYLE_RULES = {
        32: {
            range(0, 1): 'S',
            range(1, 9): 'E',
            range(9, 33): 'F'
        },
        64: {
            range(0, 1): 'S',
            range(1, 12): 'E',
            range(12, 65): 'F'
        }
    }

    STRUCT_RULES = {
        31: lambda bits: struct.unpack('>f', struct.pack('>L', bits))[0],
        63: lambda bits: struct.unpack('>d', struct.pack('>Q', bits))[0]
    }

    def __init__(self, width, var, master=None, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.buttons = [tkinter.ttk.Button(self) for _ in range(width)]
        self.var = var
        self.configure_all()
        self.grid_all()

    def configure_all(self):
        for column, button in enumerate(self.buttons):
            button.configure(text='0', width=1, style=self.get_style(column),
                             command=self.get_command(column))

    def get_style(self, column):
        for key, value in self.STYLE_RULES[len(self.buttons)].items():
            if column in key:
                return f'{value}.TButton'
        raise KeyError(f'column {column} has no style')

    def get_command(self, column):
        return lambda: self.toggle_bit(column)

    def toggle_bit(self, column):
        button = self.buttons[column]
        button['text'] = int(not int(button['text']))
        self.update_var()

    def update_var(self):
        bits = index = 0
        for index, button in enumerate(reversed(self.buttons)):
            bits |= int(button['text']) << index
        self.var.set(self.STRUCT_RULES[index](bits))

    def grid_all(self):
        for column, button in enumerate(self.buttons):
            button.grid(row=0, column=column)


class Equation(tkinter.ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, width, var, master=None, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.width = width
        self.var = var
        self.sign = tkinter.ttk.Label(self)
        self.times_1 = tkinter.ttk.Label(self)
        self.exponent = tkinter.ttk.Label(self)
        self.times_2 = tkinter.ttk.Label(self)
        self.fraction = tkinter.ttk.Label(self)
        self.configure_all()
        self.grid_all()

    def configure_all(self):
        self.sign.configure(text='1', style='S.TLabel')
        self.times_1.configure(text='×')
        self.exponent.configure(text='2 ** 0', style='E.TLabel')
        self.times_2.configure(text='×')
        self.fraction.configure(text='1', style='F.TLabel')

    def grid_all(self):
        self.sign.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.times_1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.exponent.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.times_2.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.fraction.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FloatToy.main()
```